# Wordpress match url for custom content without post or page

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new in wordpress.

I want to use two tables and display some content without creating pages or posts.

The matched url will be something like this:

`/[category]/[image]` - `/nature/green-tree`

My method was to check the url in index.php from theme and split the url and create a mini route system just for the gallery. But I think it is not the smartest idea.
I don't want to use gallery plugins because I'm already using one, and this is a change that I need to to.
What is the best method to do this?

Comment: I would personally use a gallery plugin, so that WordPress can manage the pages and urls, as well as the image meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need custom rewrite rules. Here is how you can do it by yourself.

If you are using a theme then open the `functions.php` file and enter the following code, otherwise if you are using a plugin, place this code somewhere in your plugin, but make sure, that it is loading immediately.

```
function registerCustomUrl($rewrite)
{
    $rewrites       =   $rewrite->rules;
    $newRewrites    =   array();

    $newRewrites['([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$']  =   'index.php?gallery_category=$matches[1]&gallery_image=$matches[2]';

    foreach($rewrites as $rk => $rv)
    {
        $newRewrites[$rk]   =   $rv;
    }

    $rewrite->rules =   $newRewrites;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules',    'registerCustomUrl');

function registerCustomQueryVars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'gallery_category';
    $vars[] = 'gallery_image';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars',    'registerCustomQueryVars');

function myCustomTemplateRedirect()
{
    global $wp_query;

    if(
        isset($wp_query->query_vars['gallery_category']) &&
        !empty($wp_query->query_vars['gallery_category']) &&
        isset($wp_query->query_vars['gallery_image']) &&
        !empty($wp_query->query_vars['gallery_image'])
    )
    {
    // Within your custom template file you are able to
        // use any theme function like the get_header(), get_footer(), etc
        require_once('path/to/your/custom/template/file.php');
        exit(0);
    }
}
add_action("template_redirect", 'myCustomTemplateRedirect');
```